# Trying to get property of non-object when using One to Many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I keep getting this error when trying to get the name of the user who created a post.

My models look like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable, CanResetPassword;

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

&

```
class Post extends Model {

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I try to display the name by doing this in my view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $post->user->name }}</td>          
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public function getAdminIndex() {
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    $comments = Comment::all();
    $likes = Like::all();
    $users = User::all();

    return view('admin.index', ['posts' => $posts, 'comments' => $comments, 'likes' => $likes, 'users' => $users]);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means not all posts have user, so do something like this:

```
<td>{{ optional($post->user)->name }}</td>
```

Or:

```
<td>{{ empty($post->user) ? 'No user' : $post->user->name }}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, optional did the trick, will accept your answer as soon as I'm able to!